# Creating Zip and Force Downloading - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, zip

I am using Laravel 4.2 and am looking to setup an area where a zip file is produced for the user to download.

I keep getting the error

> The file "myzip.zip does not exist"

My current code is :

```
// Here we choose the folder which will be used.
            $dirName = public_path() . '/uploads/packs/'.$pack_id;

            // Choose a name for the archive.
            $zipFileName = 'myzip.zip';

            // Create "MyCoolName.zip" file in public directory of project.
            $zip = new ZipArchive;

            if ( $zip->open( public_path() . '/' . $zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE ) === true )
            {
                // Copy all the files from the folder and place them in the archive.
                foreach ( glob( $dirName . '/*' ) as $fileName )
                {
                    $file = basename( $fileName );
                    $zip->addFile( $fileName, $file );
                }

                $zip->close();

                $headers = array(
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                );

                // Download .zip file.
                return Response::download( public_path() . '/' . $zipFileName, $zipFileName, $headers );
```

Can anyone help me, As to why I am getting the does not exist error?

Thank You!

Comment: If you check your directory through ftp, is the zip created or not?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses

**Creating A File Download Response**

```
return Response::download($pathToFile);

return Response::download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

Maybe you should avoid to repeat the second

```
$zipFileName
```

in your last line of code.

Comment: In 5.2, that would be `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);`

Answer (score 1):

You can “create a zip of multiple files and download in PHP” below way.

To create a zip of multiple files and download with PHP it has some below features:

- It will create a zip file by using ZipArchive Library.
- Before creating a file it will check file exist or not.
- If a file exists then it will remove the file.
- If file not exists then it will create
- a zip file with multiple passed for it.
- When the zip is ready it will be auto download.

  ```
  //get path of files
  $path = base_path();
  $file_path = $path."/../uploads/advatise/";
  //getting data from database
  $row = $this->getRow($ids);
  //if data exist
  if($row) {
      //multiple images in single attrubute
      $images=$row->advertise_image;
      $images=explode(",",$images);
      //creating zip object
      $zip = new ZipArchive();
      //creating file name
      $DelFilePath="images".$row->id.".zip";
      //if file exists then to delete it
      if(file_exists($file_path.$DelFilePath)) {
          unlink ($file_path.$DelFilePath);
      }
      //if not exist then to create zip file
      if ($zip->open($file_path.$DelFilePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) 
  != TRUE) {
          die ("Could not open archive");
      }
      //loop on the images/file to add in zip
      foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
          $zip->addFile($file_path.$image,$image);
      }
      // close and save archive
      $zip->close();
      //opening zip and saving directly on client machine
      header("Location:".Request::root()."/uploads/advatise/".$DelFilePath);
  }
  exit;
  ```